# I can't restore my monero wallet gui

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monero-wallet-rpc, mnemonic-seed, wallet-recovery, remote-node

My account in my wallet is not correct. When I restore my wallet with seeds I write date when I create my wallet. Remote node was synchronized and in transaction history i see only one transaction ( oldest transaction). How I can a restore my wallet with complited history transaction and all my coin in account ?

Help brooo... :)